# Manipulate json into an object with a different structure automatically

Tags: javascript, json

I have a huge JSON file. It's not in the correct structure and I have no control over the structure.  It is data coming from a group of routers based on timestamp.  I'm trying to create an object structure that combines all the info for a given router into a router object with timestamp etc. as arrays.   @quodlibetor was a big help getting me close to this.  I also want to automatically name the properties of the object from the name of the name val pairs in the json.

My aim is to autoname the properties from the names in the json file and to restructure it into an object that looks like this (I'm open to suggestions on the structure this just seemed the most organized way to do it).

This is the structure I want:

```
    {
        "Router": [
            {
                "routerName": "RouterID1",
                "TimeStamp": [
                    "2012/01/01 06:00:00",
                    "2013/01/01 06:00:00",
                    "2014/01/01 06:00:00"
                ],
                "OutputBITS": [
                    "23235",
                    "29903",
                    "22103"
                ],
                "InputBITS": [
                    "23235",
                    "29903",
                    "22103"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Although trying to create that structure I'm getting close but no deal:

```
{
    "RouterID1": {
        "timeStamp": [
            {
                "timeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:00:00"
            },
            {
                "timeStamp": "2013/01/01 06:00:00"
            },
            {
                "timeStamp": "2014/01/01 06:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "OutputBITS": [
            {
                "OutputBITS": "23235"
            },
            {
                "OutputBITS": "23235"
            },
            {
                "OutputBITS": "23235"
            }
        ],
        "InputBITS": [
            {
                "InputBITS": "29903"
            },
            {
                "InputBITS": "29903"
            },
            {
                "InputBITS": "29903"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

ORIGINAL JSON:

```
json = [
         {
              "Router": "RouterID1",
              "TimeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:00:00",
              "OutputBITS": "23235",
              "InputBITS":  "29903"
         },   
          {
              "Router": "RouterID1",
              "TimeStamp": "2013/01/01 06:00:00",
              "OutputBITS": "23235",
              "InputBITS":  "29903"
         },   
          {
              "Router": "RouterID1",
              "TimeStamp": "2014/01/01 06:00:00",
              "OutputBITS": "23235",
              "InputBITS":  "29903"
         },
         {
              "Router": "RouterID3",
              "TimeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:05:00",
              "OutputBITS": "21235",
              "InputBITS":  "22103"
         },
         {
             "Router": "RouterID3",
             "TimeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:05:00",
             "OutputBITS": "21235",
             "InputBITS":  "22103"
        },
        {
            "Router": "RouterID4",
            "TimeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:05:00",
            "OutputBITS": "21235",
            "InputBITS":  "22103"
       },
       {
           "Router": "RouterID4",
           "TimeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:05:00",
           "OutputBITS": "21235",
           "InputBITS":  "22103"
      }
      ];
```

CODE:

```
    //  Create routers object    
    var routers = {};


       for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
        var router_name = json[i].Router;
        router_name = (router_name.replace(/-/g, ""));  //take hyphen out or router name

        if (!routers[router_name]){
            // add properties to the router object thanks to @@quodlibetor

            // instead of using timeStamp is something like json[i] or json.[name] or some
            // way to reference each json property and not have to type it in?

            routers[router_name] = { timeStamp : [], OutputBITS : [], InputBITS : [] };
        }

                routers[router_name].timeStamp.push({
                    timeStamp : json[i].TimeStamp
                }); 
                 routers[router_name].OutputBITS.push({
                     OutputBITS : json[i].OutputBITS
                }); 
                routers[router_name].InputBITS.push({
                    InputBITS : json[i].InputBITS
                });  
    }; 

    console.log(routers);
    });
     </script>
```

Comment: Whats the JSON you have at the beginning?

Comment: [ { is what is at the beginning. It's all up there. I'll check out your answer below.

Comment: I didn't meant that, I meant the JSON you get and want to manipulate.

Comment: @BenniKa oops forgot to post that. one sec and I'll add it to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```
var router = {router: []}, i, j, k, l, inArray, routerName, thisRouter;

for(i=0,j=json.length;i<j;++i) {
    inArray = false;

    routerName = json[i].Router;

    for(k=0,l=router.router.length;k<l;++k) {
        if(router.router[k].name === routerName) {
            inArray = true; --k; l = k;
        }
    }

    if(inArray === true) {
        router.router[k].TimeStamp.push(json[i].TimeStamp);
        router.router[k].OutputBITS.push(json[i].OutputBITS);
        router.router[k].InputBITS.push(json[i].InputBITS);
    } else {
        thisRouter = {name: routerName, TimeStamp: [json[i].TimeStamp], OutputBITS: [json[i].OutputBITS], InputBITS: [json[i].InputBITS]};

        router.router.push(thisRouter);
    }
}

console.log(router);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It's probably because you didn't have the original JSON(it's up there now) but it's throwing and error:  routers['name'] = Router;
Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined

Comment: sorry, i was away from the computer, i will programm it now.

Comment: @rd42 now it should do what you want it to do.