# Obtain a different JSON object structure in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm Working on AngularJS.
In this part of the project my goal is to obtain a JSON structure after filling a form with some particulars values.

Here's the fiddle of my simple form: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9h93/5/)

With the form I will do a query to KairosDB, that is my NoSql Database, I will query data from it by a JSON object. The form is structured in this way:

- a **Name**
- a certain Number of **Tags**, with **Tag Id** ("ch" for example) and **tag value** ("932" for example)
- a certain Number of **Aggregators** to manipulate data coming from DB
- **Start Timestamp** and **End Timestamp** (now they are static and only included in the final JSON Object)

After filling this form, with my code I'll obtain for example this JSON object:

```
{
    "metrics": [
    {
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": "ch",
          "value": "932"
        },
        {
          "id": "ch",
          "value": "931"
        }
      ],
      "aggregators": {
        "name": "sum",
        "sampling": [
          {
            "value": "1",
            "unit": "milliseconds",
            "type": "SUM"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "cache_time": 0,
  "start_absolute": 123,
  "end_absolute": 1234

}
```

Unfortunately, KairosDB accepts a different structure, and as you could see, Tag id "ch" doesn't hase an "id" string before, or for example, Tag values coming from the same tag id are grouped together

```
{
  "metrics": [
    {
      "tags": {
        "ch": [
          "932",
          "931"
        ]
      },
      "name": "AIENR",
      "aggregators": [
        {
          "name": "sum",
          "sampling": {
            "value": "1",
            "unit": "milliseconds"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cache_time": 0,
  "start_absolute": 1367359200000,
  "end_absolute": 1386025200000
}
```

**My question is:** Is there a way to obtain the JSON structure like the one accepted by Kairos DB with an Angular JS form?. Thanks to everyone. 
I've seen this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126666/manipulate-json-into-an-object-with-a-different-structure-automatically) as the one more similar to mine but it isn't in AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd do the refactoring work in the backend - Have what ever server interfaces sends and receives data do the manipulation - Otherwise you'll end up needing to refactor your data inside Angular anywhere you want to use that dataset.

Where as doing it in the backend would put it in a single access point.

Of course, you could do it in Angular, just replace `userString` in the `submitData` method with a copy of the array and replace the tags section with data in the new format, and likewise refactor the returned result to the correct format when you get a reply.

Comment: Consider this fiddle for example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DrQ77/64/) . Is there a way to dynamically assign a different name to  "Options" field in the Questions variable? I want to obtain a similar object but with some of the field dynamics. Thanks